Show divergence to infinity of $\frac{n}{(\log{n})^2}$ using the definition of divergence to infinity

Show the divergence to infinity of $$\frac{n}{(\log{n})^2}$$ using the definition of divergence to infinity.

I know that the definition of divergence to infinity for $u_n$ is that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then $u_n>\epsilon$. However I don't know how to find $N$ in the case of $u_n=n/(\log{n})^2$, and so I don't know how to show that it diverges to infinity.
Thank you for your help.

$\log n=3\log  n^{1/3} <3 n^{1/3}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

@geetha290krm That's great, thanks. Maye you should post that as an answer?

This depends heavily on how you define $\log n$. Using one of the most common definitions, for any $c>0$ you have
$$
\log n=\int_1^n\frac1t\,dt\leq\int_1^n\frac1{t^{1-c}}\,dt=\frac{n^c-1}c\leq\frac{n^c}c.
$$
Therefore, for any $c>0$, you have
$$
\frac{n^{2c}}{\log n}\geq cn^c,
$$
and then
$$
\frac{n^{4c}}{(\log n)^2}\geq c^2n^{2c}.
$$
With $c=1/4$ this is
$$
\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}\geq \frac{n^{1/2}}{16}.
$$
Now given any $M>0$, let $N=256M^2$. For any $n>N$,
$$
\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}\geq \frac{n^{1/2}}{16}>\frac{16M}{16}=M.
$$

A minor variant on the comments and answers above: the limit $t/\log(t)^2$ as $t \to \infty$ can be calculated in terms of $s=\log(t)$ and $e^s=t$. That is, we want to show that $\lim_{s \to \infty}e^s/s^2$. Now $e^s = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k/k!$, hence for $s\geq 0$ we have $e^s\geq s^k/k!$ for any $k\in \mathbb N$. In particular, $e^s\geq s^3/3!$ and hence $e^s/s^2\geq s/3! \to \infty$ as $s \to \infty$.
[Note that this argument makes it clear that $e^s/p(s) \to \infty$ for any polynomial function $p(s)$.]

This is probably more complicated than it needs to be, but here is a proof:
Note that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{e^k}{k^2}$$
using the substitution $n=e^k$.
Note that $k\ge11$ implies $\dfrac{e^k}{k^2}>\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}$.
Proof that when $k\ge11$, $\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}\ge\lceil k\rceil$:
Let $\phi(k):=\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}\ge\lceil k\rceil$.
For all $k$ in $[11,12)$, $2^k\ge2048$ and $k<12$ so $\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}>2048/12>12\ge\lceil k\rceil$.
When $k\ge11$, assume that $\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}\ge\lceil k\rceil$. This means $\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}\ge k$ so $\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}\ge \dfrac{2^k\times2}{k^2\times1.5}\ge\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}\times\dfrac43\ge k\times\dfrac43\ge k+2\ge\lceil k+1\rceil$.
So $\forall k\ge11(\phi(k)\Rightarrow\phi(k+1))$. Combined with base case, $\forall k\ge11(\phi(k))$ is provable so $\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{2^k}{k^2}=\infty$.
$\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{e^k}{k^2}=\infty$ follows from a simple bounding argument.
